# Save a token as a string in PHP

Tags: php, token

I have a token.php file that generates the token of my server in order to make a stream to work. What i want to do is to response from the server as a string
i have tryed the code below but it's not working

```
$my_var = file_get_contents('example.com/token.php'); 
echo $my_var;
```

Comment: what doesn't work woth what you did?

Comment: with file_get_contents you literally get the contents of the file aka the php code, i think you are looking for include/require

Comment: for one: 'example.com/' would search the directory 'example.com' not 'http://example.com'

Comment: You missing http/https :/

Comment: This is the response : "Warning: file_get_contents(My token webpage link): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\redirect.php on line 3"

Comment: As I said, it searched the directory 'example.com' which is presumably nonexistant.

Comment: Wont get `HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` for a directory.. Lets not guess whats the actual code?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ??? It would search example.com for the file, if example.com doesn't exist it's not going to find the file and it *would* return a 404 File Not Found error

Comment: No file_get_contents will not fallback to doing a HTTP request if a directory is not found.

Comment: hmm well then i guess i stand corrected :)

Comment: @TyQ. My guess is the OP is calling the same site and the reverse proxy is attempting to do load localhost but as it does not exist its 404. But who knows..

Comment: Clearly check your path and try again, everyone's suggestion is good.
Maybe the fault is your path.

Comment: I tried to test with another page and it's working . In my token.php file i made it to be only visited by a browser with a custom user-agent . I'm using user-agent switcher from chrome but it's not working with my page with custom user-agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting literal content from token.php
Try:

```
$my_var = file_get_contents('http://example.com/token.php');
echo $my_var;
```

Comment: I tried to test with another page and it's working . In my token.php file i made it to be only visited by a browser with a custom user-agent . I'm using user-agent switcher from chrome but it's not working with my page with custom user-agent

Comment: But file_get_contents() is executed from server not from browser!
If you need to specify an user-agent, use curl instead of file_get_contents().